# Users with Subscriber role in Wordpress cannot see & access CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, configuration, roles

Users connected with the "subscriber" role in WordPress do not see CiviCRM nor access to it (404 error). It works well with WP admin role.
I believe I have configured correctly the permissions in Administer -> Users & Permissions -> WordPress Access Control.
Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Can you check if the url doesn't have wp-admin/admin.php?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using? And did it work until you did an update?

Comment: Also, you said "I believe I have configured correctly the permissions" - can you please edit your question to tell us (and/or use a screenshot) to show us the permissions?

Comment: @ Pradeep: as told in my question, admin role can access CiviCRM so admin.php is there
@ Jon: I use version Version 5.14.1, first version installed (I will update it on the next days)
I have configured correctly the permissions in Administer -> Users & Permissions -> WordPress Access Control as you can see:
![Valid XHTML](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCl9YqYon-ngyqJJ0FTVgvIEAqU?e=621ahu).

Comment: Could you clarify what level of access you want subscribers to have? This isn't clear from your question.

Comment: The subscriber should be able to do what a "normal user" can do in a NP organisation : create, modify, delete and use contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tested all the possibilities by checking and unchecking all the options marked in the WordPress Access Control pane, I found that the box "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" must be be ticked. Otherwise you dont have access to CiviCRM. Strange because it is told to give this to trusted roles only. The well done documentation is unfortunately lacking on this subject.

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend giving subscribers this level of access to CiviCRM. What do you want subscribers to be be able to do on your site? You can find the documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Comment: The subscriber should be able to do what a "normal user" can do in a NP organisation : create, modify, delete and use contacts.

Comment: The 'subscriber' role in WordPress is typically used to allow people to sign up to receive information from a website. It doesn't normally give them permission to access any admin functions or the WordPress dashboard. Perhaps you are using this role in a different way but it sounds like an unusual set up. As it says in the manual the permission to access the CiviCRM back end should only be given to trusted roles and I wouldn't recommend giving it to anyone outside the staff team.

Comment: If you are using the role for staff I would be inclined to use one of the other WordPress roles that typically have greater access such as 'administrator' or 'editor'. Alternatively you could create a new role for this purpose. This page that explains roles and permissions may help: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: Thank you William, I fully understand what you mean, but... this doesn't explain why I need to give the " "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" to see CiviCRM menu. The problem will be the same with all other roles... According me, this is a weakness in the security of CiviCRM under WP.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve I'm afraid. Typically only staff would have access to the CiviCRM back-end and the menu. Visitors to the site wouldn't have any access to either.

Comment: We are using WP just for CiviCRM, no other need. So anonymous visitors do not have access to CiviCRM. Only connected users have access to CiviCRM to edit contacts. WP's Subscriber role seemed to be the best option for this. If you have another solution....

Comment: In some sense it doesn't really matter which role you use as long as you set up the permissions correctly to give people the right level of access. However, it can be confusing for people if you go against convention and use a role for a purpose that it isn't really intended. For that reason I would suggest giving staff the 'administrator' or 'editor' roles or perhaps create a new role specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, thanks again William